# Convert Arraylist of some Class type into JSON format using Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I want to hit an api using Alamofire in which I have to pass parameters as :

```
"reminder":
[
  {
    "isAlarmOn": "true",
    "time": "06:29 PM"
  },
  {
    "isAlarmOn": "true",
    "time": "06:30 AM"
  }
]
```

For achieving this, I Created an Array as

```
var reminderArray : [AlarmRequestModel] = [AlarmRequestModel]()
```

where AlarmRequestModel is Like ,

**AlarmRequestModel.swift**

```
import Foundation
class AlarmRequestModel {
    var time : String = "12:00 PM"

    init(time : String){
        if !time.isEmpty{
            self.time = time
        }

    }
}
```

and filled reminderArray as

```
func setArray() {
        reminderArray.insert(AlarmRequestModel(time: "5:00 PM"), atIndex: 0)
        reminderArray.insert(AlarmRequestModel(time: "6:00 PM"), atIndex: 1)
        reminderArray.insert(AlarmRequestModel(time: "7:00 PM"), atIndex: 2)
        reminderArray.insert(AlarmRequestModel(time: "8:00 PM"), atIndex: 3)
    }
```

And while hitting the Api , I Declared the parameters as

```
 func hitApi()
    {
        let parameters  : [String:AnyObject] = [
            "reminder" : reminderArray.description,
            ]

        print("parmeters : \(parameters)")
    }
```

But I didn't get the expected output , 
the output was like ->

```
 parmeters :["reminder": [My_Swaasth.AlarmRequestModel,My_Swaasth.AlarmRequestModel,My_Swaasth.AlarmRequestModel,My_Swaasth.AlarmRequestModel]]
```

Please anyone Suggest , What changes Do I Need to do in order to achieve the desired output.

Comment: you can also include swiftyJSON   https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a protocoll called CustomStringConvertible which has the

```
var description: String property
```

But that won't result the desired output. So I'd rather implement a parameter value for AlarmRequestModel

```
extension AlarmRequestModel {
     var parameterValue: Dictionary<String, String> {
         return ["isAlarmOn": "true", "time": self.time]
     }
}
```

And use this like

```
reminderArray.map() { reminder in return reminder.parameterValue }
```

here:

```
    let parameters  : [String:AnyObject] = [
        "reminder" : reminderArray.map() { reminder in return reminder.parameterValue },
        ]
```

Comment: now m getting this output   .. "reminder": <_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray 0x16c6b2f0>(
{
    time = "9:00 AM";
},
{
    time = "2:31 PM";
},
{
    time = "9:00 PM";
}
)

Comment: It is because you use `[String:AnyObject]`, you can change it `[String:Any]` and the output should be good. Otherwise if you want to parse it with `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(...)` to JSON NSData keep the AnyObject type.

Answer (score 0):

```
func hitApi()
{

    var JSONarray: [Dictionary<String,String>] = []

    for (index,_) in reminderArray.enumerate()
    {
        JSONarray.append(["isAlarmOn":"true","time": reminderArray[index].time])
    }

    let bytes = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(JSONarray, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
    var jsonObj = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(bytes, options: .MutableLeaves) as! [Dictionary<String, String>]

    print("\"reminder\":\(jsonObj)")
}
```

You also want to change your Alarm Request Model to this:

```
class AlarmRequestModel {

    var time : String!

    init(time : String){
        if !time.isEmpty{
            self.time = time
        }

    }   
}
```